# Return typed object from method

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

Is there a way to make a function return the type of object I pass in? I would like to call the one method below to return the type I pass in. Is that possible? Should I even be trying to do this? Is there a better way...short of having two different methods?

Currently, I tried the first two calls and I get back (with the first call) what looks like a dictionary with a system.object[] in the value part of the dictionary. Screen shot below might show it better than my explanation. I ask this as I might have more types that I need to deserialize and don't want to have a different method for each.

```
var firstTry = this.Deserialize(path, typeof(ObservableCollection<ListItemPair>();

var secondTry = this.Deserialize(path, typeof(ListItemPair));

var thirdTry = this.Deserialize(path, typeof(SomeOtherObject));

public static object Deserialize(string jsonFile, object type)
{
    var myObject = new object();

    try
    {
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(jsonFile))
        {
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            string json = r.ReadToEnd();

            myObject = serializer.Deserialize<object>(json);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

    return myObject ;
}

public class ListItemPair
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;

        set;
    }

    public object Value
    {
        get;

        set;
    }
}
```

object created:

[image]

Comment: you can call .GetType() on any object in .NET if that suffices

Comment: So, I return myObject.GetType()?

Comment: Well you can still return the deserialized object, but once you have it back you can call .GetType() on the object... Now if you want to know the type compile time that's a different story, but if you just want to output the type or something then .GetType() should work

Comment: You could also make the Deserialize() method generic, where you specify the type and know the return with your `T` parameter. In which case you could call the generic function with whatever type is to be deserialized.

Comment: Not getting it. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that someone else provided an example. I'll try that one. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create a generic method. Your `Deserialize()` method would look something like this:

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(string jsonFile)
{
    T myObject = default(T);

    try
    {
        using (var r = new StreamReader(jsonFile))
        {
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            myObject = serializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

    return myObject;
}
```

In this example `T` is a type parameter. When invoking this method, you can pass the type like this:

```
var firstTry = Deserialize<ObservableCollection<ListItemPair>>(path);
var secondTry = Deserialize<ListItemPair>(path);
var thirdTry = Deserialize<SomeOtherObject>(path);
```

One side note: I wouldn't recommend silently swallowing an exception. In this case, it is expected that the deserialization can fail. Therefore, I would change it to a `TryDeserialize()` method:

```
public static bool TryDeserialize<T>(string jsonFile, out T myObject)
{
    try
    {
        using (var r = new StreamReader(jsonFile))
        {
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            myObject = serializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        myObject = default(T);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Excellent! That is what I needed. I just did not understand how to construct it. Thank you.

Comment: Right. I just have not filled in the catch yet. I do like how you have restructured the method though and will change mine accordingly.